# Unit testing Spring Boot application endpoints

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I have a small Spring Boot application with a defined health endpoint at "/health". This is defined in code by:

```
@Component
public class MyHealthEndpoint implements HealthIndicator {
  public Health health() {
    # ...
    # returns health info as JSON here 
    # ...
  }
}
```

So when running the application a visit to the endpoint at localhost/health returns some application health info.

My question is: what is the best way to test this?

I would like to do a unit test of the MyHealthEndpoint class and I've tried instantiating it in my test class with @Autowired which doesn't work.
Also tried instantiating it in the test class with

```
MyHealthEndpoint testHealthEndpoint = new MyHealthEndpoint();
```

But this just returns an empty new class with no health info, so obviously the dependency injection/IOC in Spring Boot doesn't register it, or I'm just too much of a newbie to Spring to know how to do it correctly.

Is the only solution to run an integration test by starting the application and running a test http GET call directly to the endpoint and then asserting the returned JSON or do you have better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Sprint test context framework
Check this:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations

You can find the lib here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test

You should annotate the test classes  (or a parent class) with @ContextConfiguration and you can set your config xml (locations parameter) and config Java classes (classes parameter)
And if you use SpringMVC add @WebAppConfiguration annotation too

If it is configured you can use @Autowired in tests.

Comment: Meanwhile I started to use Spring *MVC Test framework* https://spring.io/blog/2012/11/12/spring-framework-3-2-rc1-spring-mvc-test-framework, I think this is the right solution for testing Spring based REST endpoints